# Compute the average of a set of covariance matrixes in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, statistics, finance

I am trying to analyse the impact of error in mean-variance analysis from historical data. In particular, I am trying to calculate average efficient frontiers. I have the returns and standard deviation for the five assets under consideration, as well as the correlation matrix for the five assets. I used the functions mvnrnd to generate the monthly returns and frontcon for the efficient frontier. After generating the returns, I calculate the covariance of these. I run 10,000 simulations.

I have written the function below to do what I need, but it fails on the 150 yrs attempt with the message below. This is the my first time writing anything in MATLAB (which I need to use), so I am not 100% sure of my code. It does produce graphs for the 2 yr and 30 yr time period, but I don't know if the failure of the 150 yr is due to my bad programming or not. In particular I wasn't sure how to calculate the average covariance across the 10,000 simulations. I have searched elsewhere as best I can but if the answer exists out there then I haven't found the correct phrasing to find it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. My code is below the error message.

```
> Warning: Candidate solution is infeasible due to a bad pivot.

> In lcprog>lcprealitycheck at 294 
> In lcprog at 251 In qplcprog at 247 
> In portopt at 249 
> In frontcon at 231 In AverageEfficientFrontiers at 36 
> Error using portopt (line 256)
> 
> No portfolios satisfy all input constraints for maximum-return
> portfolio. Possibly unbounded problem.
> 
> Error in frontcon (line 231)    [PRisk, PRoR, PWts] = portopt(ERet,
> ECov, NPts, RTarget,    ConSet, ...
> 
> Error in AverageEfficientFrontiers (line 36) [Risk, Return, Weights] =
> frontcon(AverageReturn, AverageCovariance, 10);"


function [] = AverageEfficientFrontiers( Years, Simulations )

AssetReturns = [0.006,0.01,0.014,0.018,0.022];
AssetStDev = [0.085,0.08,0.095,0.09,0.1];
CorrelationMatrix = [1,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3; 
                     0.3,1,0.3,0.3,0.3;
                     0.3,0.3,1,0.3,0.3;
                     0.3,0.3,0.3,1,0.3;
                     0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3,1];
Months = Years*12;
CovarianceMatrix = corr2cov(AssetStDev,CorrelationMatrix);
% Preallocating avoids the need for MATLAB to copy the data from one array 
% to another inside the loop
TotalCumulativeReturn = zeros(Simulations,5);
PeriodCovariance = zeros(Simulations,5,5);

for i=1:Simulations
    MonthlyReturns = mvnrnd(AssetReturns,CovarianceMatrix,Months);
%   If A is a nonempty matrix, then prod(A) treats the columns of A as 
%   vectors and returns a row vector of the products of each column. 
%   A(i,:) is the ith row of A.
    TotalCumulativeReturn(i,:) = prod(1+MonthlyReturns)-1;
%   For matrix input X, where each row is an observation, and each column 
%   is a variable, cov(X) is the covariance matrix.
%   http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/cov.html
    PeriodCovariance(i,:,:) = cov(MonthlyReturns)*Months;
end
% If A is a nonempty, nonvector matrix, then mean(A) treats the columns of 
% A as vectors and returns a row vector whose elements are the mean of each 
% column.
AverageReturn = mean(TotalCumulativeReturn);
AverageCovariance = mean(PeriodCovariance);
% http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html
AverageCovariance = reshape(AverageCovariance, [5,5]);
[Risk, Return, Weights] = frontcon(AverageReturn, AverageCovariance, 10);

plot(Risk, Return);
end
```

Comment: Can you post the code where the function is called?

Comment: I am just calling it from the command window. E.g. AverageEfficientFrontiers(2, 10000). AverageEfficientFrontiers(30, 10000) AverageEfficientFrontiers(150, 10000)